# How to reverse post navigation at bottom of post

Tags: query-posts, navigation, child-theme

I am using a child theme derived from twentythirteen.  I wanted to have my posts displayed in chronological order(ascending).  I tried adding the code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98444/82909) to index.php but for some reason that didn't seem to work.  So instead I got the plugin ["Advanced Post Types Order"](http://www.nsp-code.com/premium-plugins/wordpress-plugins/advanced-post-types-order/) and that seemed to work fine, in regards to displaying the posts in the right order.

However now when I want to display a single post, the navigation links are backwards.  It displays:

[image]

The two links should be just reversed, i.e.

**<-- post #1** for the "previous" post, and **post#3 -->** for the "next" post.

I looked at file single.php, and found it was calling twentythirteen_post_nav() in functions.php.  And inside that function, I found the two lines:

```
   <?php previous_post_link( '%link', _x( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> %title', 'Previous post link', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>
   <?php next_post_link( '%link', _x( '%title <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Next post link', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>
```

So I tried just reversing their order, i.e.

```
   <?php next_post_link( '%link', _x( '%title <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Next post link', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>
   <?php previous_post_link( '%link', _x( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> %title', 'Previous post link', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>
```

but surprisingly, that didn't change anything(!).  I know I am getting into this function, because if I change some characters (like changing the &rarr to -->) that shows up.  Iss there some funny CSS tricks going on here I'm not aware of?

BTW this is my first WordPress project, so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap their *arguments* & rel tag too:

```
<?php echo str_replace( 'rel="next"', 'rel="prev"', get_next_post_link( '%link', _x( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> %title', 'Previous post link', 'twentythirteen' ) ) ); ?>
<?php echo str_replace( 'rel="prev"', 'rel="next"', get_previous_post_link( '%link', _x( '%title <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'Next post link', 'twentythirteen' ) ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help any.  Still displaying **post #3** on the left, and **post #1** on the right.  The arguments mostly just specify whether the arrow appears to the left or right of the title.  Otherwise they are identical, except for the "Previous post link" and "Next post link"; I don't know how they are used.  Those two strings don't appear anywhere else in the code, so they are not being compared to anything.

Comment: You're right - the functions output a `rel=prev|next` tag, which is probably what the CSS is targeting. You can edit the CSS, or swap the tags with string replace (see revision).

Comment: That worked!  I saw the rel tags when I dumped the page source, but I couldn't figure out how they worked in the CSS.  Swapping them on the fly as the strings are returned from get_next_post_link and get_previous_post_link is brilliant.  Thank you so much!